# WARNING: The directory '/home/jovyan/.cache/pip'

Tags: docker

I have a problem installing jupyter in docker.
I have Docker installed and ubuntu supported.

The dcoker_compose.yml file

```
jupyter-image:
    container_name: "jupyter-image"
    build:
        context: ./dockerfile_jupyter_notebook
    volumes:
        - $ {WD} / notebooks: / home / jovyan / work
        - $ {WD} / q_pack: / home / jovyan / work / q_pack
        - $ {WD} / mlflow: / mlflow-image
    environment:
        MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL: http: // minio-image: 9000
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: minio-image
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: minio-image-pass
        MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI: http: // mlflow-image: 5500
    ports:
        - "8888: 8888"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

USER root

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    fix-permissions $CONDA_DIR && \
    fix-permissions /home/$NB_USER && \
    apt update && \
    apt-get install curl -y

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/home/jovyan/work/q_pack"
    
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--no-browser","--NotebookApp.token=''","--NotebookApp.password=''", "--allow-root"]


# Another way to give root access without password in the compose
    # environment:
    #   GRANT_SUDO: "yes"
    # user:
    #   "root"
```

It supposedly installs, but I don't have any directories in Jupyter / home / jovyan / work

while installing it crashes an error

```
WARNING: The directory '/home/jovyan/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

Comment: Have you copied your `docker-compose.yml` file correctly?  There's a lot of extra spaces in it, and you have an unusual variable reference `${WD}` where you probably mean the current host directory `.`.  Both of these could cause missing content in the container.

Answer (score 0):

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    minio-image:
        container_name: minio-image
        build:
            context: ./dockerfile_minio
        restart: always
        working_dir: "/minio-image/storage"
        volumes:
            - ${WD}/minio/storage:/minio-image/storage
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        environment:
            MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio-image
            MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio-image-pass
        command: server /minio-image/storage

    mlflow-image:
        container_name: "mlflow-image"
        build:
            context: ./dockerfile_mlflowserver
        working_dir: "/mlflow-image"
        volumes:
            - ${WD}/mlflow:/mlflow-image
        environment:
            MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL: http://minio-image:9000
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: minio-image
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: minio-image-pass
        ports:
            - "5500:5500"
        command: mlflow server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5500 --backend-store-uri /mlflow-image/mlruns 


    jupyter-image:
        container_name: "jupyter-image"
        build:
            context: ./dockerfile_jupyter_notebook
        volumes:
            - ${WD}/notebooks:/home/jovyan/work
            - ${WD}/q_pack:/home/jovyan/work/q_pack
            - ${WD}/mlflow:/mlflow-image
        environment:
            MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL: http://minio-image:9000
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: minio-image
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: minio-image-pass    
            MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI: http://mlflow-image:5500        
        ports:    
            - "8888:8888"


    redis:
        image: redis
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - redis:/data

    superset:
        container_name: "superset"
        build:
            context: ./dockerfile_superset
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - redis
        environment:
            MAPBOX_API_KEY: ${MAPBOX_API_KEY}
            SUPERSET_HOME: /etc/superset
        ports:
            - "8088:8088"
        volumes:
            - ${WD}/superset/superset_config.py:/etc/superset/superset_config.py
            - ${WD}/superset/superset.db:/var/lib/superset/superset.db              
        
    postgres_secmaster:
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        container_name: "my_postgres"
        ports:
            - 5431:5431                
        environment:
            - SHARED_PASSWORD=password
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=posgres349
        volumes:
            - ${WD}/postgress_db/scripts/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ 
            - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    pgadmin:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        container_name: "pgadmin"
        environment:
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "guest"
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "guest"
        volumes:
            - ${WD}/pgadmin/:/var/lib/pgadmin 
        ports:
            - 1234:80
        depends_on:
            - postgres_secmaster
    
    postgres:
        image: postgres
        container_name: "airflow_postgres"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow   
        volumes:
            - pg_data_airflow:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            
    airflow:
        image: airflow
        container_name: "my_airflow"
        build:
            context: ./dockerfile_airflow
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - EXECUTOR=Local
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
        volumes:
            - ${WD}/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ${WD}/q_pack:/usr/local/airflow/dags/q_pack
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        command: webserver

volumes:
    pg_data:
        external: false
        name: pg_data
    pg_data_airflow:
        external: false
        name: pg_data_airflow
    redis:
        external: false
        name: redis
```